# Is there any way to create new user using shinyauthr except inserting user data manually?

Tags: shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinyauthr

I want a sign up functionality just like loginUI.
I couldnt able to find anything.
I also tried shinyauthr::authUi().
I am using shiny dashboard for my project with shinyauthr
Is there any way to create new user using shinyauthr except inserting user data manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).